# Describe feature request for a WFS

Tags: wfs, describe-feature-type

I have been given a WFS GetCapabilities link as

> https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities

and asked to make Describe Feature Request from it. What is Describe Feature Request and how it can be done?

Comment: You need to look at (or parse the) the response from any WFS GetCapabilities request URL you have, because the URL you use to make a DescribeFeatureType request may be different from the base URL used for the GetCapabilities request.  In your case the URL is slightly different for example ~ `https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wfs`

Answer (score 3):

There is no secret to how a WFS works, it is all set out in the [OGC WFS Standard](https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html). There you will find a [`DescribeFeatureType`](https://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/09-025r2/09-025r2.html#142) request described as:

> The DescribeFeatureType operation returns a schema description of feature types offered by a WFS instance. The schema descriptions define how a WFS expects feature instances to be encoded on input (via Insert, Update and Replace actions) and how feature instances shall be encoded on output (in response to a GetPropertyValue, GetFeature or GetFeatureWithLock operation).

and goes on to show you the XML format for a POST request and the KVP for a GET request.

If reading the standard is too boring for you there are [excellent learning materials](https://opengeospatial.github.io/e-learning/wfs/text/basic-index.html) on how a WFS works provided by the OGC too.